# Civivolunteer Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission Line 221 ClassLoader.php

Tags: civivolunteer

Drupal 7.67
Civicrm 5.15.2
Civivolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1

I am getting the following message on a number of screens:

Warning: Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in require_once() (line 221 of /home/mysite/public_html/members/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php).

The biggest issue is the volunteer sign up screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a compatibility issue of Civi-Volunteer extension with latest version of CiviCRM. The new version of Civi-Volunteer is still not available but this issue is already [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477/files) in code repository. You can apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477.patch).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: This fixed the error message

Comment: So can you mark this as answered?